# Get numpy array with only certain indices

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a numpy function (or algorithm) that only returns the items of an array depending on and and-function of the values of two other boolean arrays.

E.g.

```
>>> b1 = numpy.array([False, False, True, True , True])
>>> b2 = numpy.array([True , False, True, False, True])
>>> v  = numpy.array([2    , 4    , 6   , 8,     10  ])
```

Then the function should return:

```
numpy.array([6, 10])
```

Because 6 and 10 are the values where both the corresponding b1 and b2 values are True.

Edited according accepted answer below:

```
>>> v[b1 & b2]
array([ 6, 10])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
v[b1 & b2]
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you ... this is the second answer of less than 10 characters with a perfect solution for my problem :-)